# VBA lookup for approximate value

Tags: vba, match, conditional-statements, criteria, vlookup

I want to perform a special VLookup where the value which is found would match two conditions:

1. The invoice number must be the same
2. The value found from Column G must be within the tolerance -100 to 100

Precisely speaking, if the first value found from Column G (e.g. -18,007) for invoice number '12345678' does not match the 2nd criteria (e.g. -18,007 + 10,000 = -8,007), -8,007 is outside the tolerance, so go to find the next value for '12345678', until it matches the 2nd criteria. 
Is that possible?

[image: Vlookup]

Below is my script:

```
Sub MyVlookup()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set myrange = Range("D:G")

    For i = 2 To lastrow

        Cells(i, 10) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 2), myrange, 4, False)

        'This following line is to test the value found is within the tolerance -100 to 100
        If (Cells(i, 10) + Cells(i, 1)) >= 100 Or (Cells(i, 10) + Cells(i, 1)) <= -100 Then

            Cells(i, 10).Value = "False" '<----I want to change this line to Lookup the next invoice number in Column D of table2

        Else: Cells(i, 10) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 2), myrange, 4, False)

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

**Edit**

The final output I want:
[image: Output]

Below is the script working with my amendments, but need to be checked:

```
Sub MyVlookup2()

    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastrow2 As Long  
    Dim diff As Double
    Const tolerance As Long = 100
    Set myrange = Range("D:G")
    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow
    For j = 2 To lastrow2
         If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(j, 4).Value Then
            diff = Cells(i, 1).Value + Cells(j, 7).Value
               If diff <= tolerance And diff >= -tolerance Then
                  Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(j, 4).Value
                  Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(j, 5).Value
                  Cells(i, 11).Value = Cells(j, 6).Value
                  Cells(i, 12).Value = Cells(j, 7).Value
               Exit For
            End If
         End If
      If j = lastrow2 Then Cells(i, 10).Value = False
    Next j
    Next i

 End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please indent your code? Left-aligned code is indecipherable.

Comment: Not very much, but I'm working on providing an answer :) You should use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of every module. I see you do not use it.

Comment: Sorry, coz I am very new to VBA, so I don't understand why to use Option Explicit though I saw this many times in other articles

Comment: `Option Explicit` prevents you from errors caused by typos. Let's say you have a variable `rng`, you code lots of stuff with it, but in one place you write accidentally `rgn`. You run your code, you see no error, but you don't understand why it's not giving you the result you wanted. The code can be perfectly written, but because of this typo, another variable will be created and you code will fail without you knowing the reason. If you had `Option Explicit`, it would tell you that you have never declared `rgn`. You would instantly see the problem and fix it.

Comment: `VLookup` is not suitable for solving your task

Comment: @Vasily Is it due to the variable 'i' move at the same time? Do you have any other suggestions to get the results I want?

Comment: @NicholasKan `vlookup` will always return you the first value which is matched with searching criteria, it does not matter how much `if` you will use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (I decided not to use `worksheetfunction.vlookup`):

```
Sub MyVlookup2()

Dim myrange As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
Dim diff As Double
Const tolerance As Long = 100
Set myrange = Range("D:G")
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    For j = 2 To lastrow2
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(j, 4).Value Then
            diff = Cells(i, 1).Value + Cells(j, 7).Value
            If diff <= tolerance And diff >= -tolerance Then
                Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(j, 7).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        If j = lastrow2 Then Cells(i, 10).Value = False
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

---

Regarding the `Option Explicit`, you should check the checkmark in <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Options...</kbd> and never bother about it again. The line will be always automatically included in every new module.
[image]

**Edit**

Since you updated your question, if you don't change the line `If j = lastrow2 Then Cells(i, 10).Value = False`, you will have blank values where a match is not found:

[image]

Comment: Hi ZygD, it works! But I want to lookup for the value for all of the column in table2 so I amended the script, could you have a look any parts wrong after amendments?

Comment: Output image updated, nothing special, the original script is searching for the value in last column in table2, what I did is to search all the values from the whole table2, so I don't know whether I made the correct amendments, especially for this line: 'If j = lastrow2 Then Cells(i, 10).Value = False'

Comment: Yes, it works, but I just wonder whether I have to make some changes to this line:'If j = lastrow2 Then Cells(i, 10).Value = False' also

Comment: I've updated the answer. That line works only when there is no match complying with the tolerance level.

Comment: Yup! I just did the same test as yours, now should be OK, Thanks a lot ZygD! You did help me a lot since this help my work~! Answer checked

Comment: Hi ZygD, I got a new problem, but it should be quite easy, could you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917686/vba-sum-variable-range?noredirect=1#comment49872947_30917686

Answer (score 1):

Try This generic Alookup code:

```
Sub RegisterUDF()
Dim s As String
s = "Approximate lookup similar strings on best consecutive character match basis" & Chr(lO) & vbLf _
& "Lookup_Value = What string to lookup" & Chr(lO) & "Tbl_array = Range to find String"
Application.MacroOptions Macro:="Alookup", Description:=s, Category:=9
End Sub


Sub UnregisterUDF()
Application-MacroOptions Macro:="Alookup", Description:=Empty, Category:=Empty
End Sub


            Function Alookup(Lookup_Value As String, Tbl_Array As Range, Optional col As Integer, Optional MinCharMatch1 As Integer) As String
            'Lookup_Value = What we are searching for
            'Tbl_Array = Range in which Lookup_Value will be searched in. Ideally should be single column
            'Col = Value to the left (negative number) or right (positive number) of the Tbl_Array which would be the answer to the function. Used as offset to Lookup_Value's range in Tbl_Array. _
                   If ommitted, the best match in Tbl_Array is populated as the answer to the function
            'MinCharMatch1 = Least number of characters that should match. If ommitted, defaulted to 6
            
            Dim i As Integer, Str As String, Value As String
            Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, cell As Range
            Dim mincharmatch As Integer
            Dim rng As Range
            
            Lookup_Valuel = UCase(Replace(Lookup_Value, " ", ""))
            Lookup_Valuel = UCase(Replace(Lookup_Valuel, "-", ""))
            Lookup_Valuel = UCase(Replace(Lookup_Valuel, ":", ""))
            Lookup_Valuel = UCase(Replace(Lookup_Valuel, "/", ""))
            Lookup_Valuel = UCase(Replace(Lookup_Valuel, ",", ""))
            
            
            If MinCharMatch1 = 0 Then
            MinCharMatch1 = 6
            End If
            

                For Each cell In Tbl_Array
                cell1 = UCase(Replace(cell, " ", ""))
                cell1 = UCase(Replace(cell1, "-", ""))
                cell1 = UCase(Replace(cell1, ":", ""))
                cell1 = UCase(Replace(cell1, "/", ""))
                cell1 = UCase(Replace(cell1, ",", ""))
    
    
    
    'Check lower len in higer len
    
        If Len(cell1) < Len(Lookup_Valuel) Then
        
        mincharmatch = WorksheetFunction.Min(Len(cell1), MinCharMatch1)
          
                For j = Len(cell1) To mincharmatch Step -1
                    If InStr(Lookup_Valuel, Left(cell1, j)) > 0 Or InStr(Lookup_Valuel, Right(cell1, j)) > 0 Then
                        If Found <> "" Then
                            If j > CInt(Mid(Found, WorksheetFunction.Search("|", Found) + 1, 99)) Then
                            Found = cell.Value2 & "|" & j
                            Set rng = cell
                            End If
                        Else
                            Found = cell.Value2 & "|" & j
                            Set rng = cell
                            
                        End If
                    GoTo nextcell
                    End If
                Next j

        
        Else

         mincharmatch = WorksheetFunction.Min(Len(Lookup_Valuel), Len(cell1), MinCharMatch1)

           
                        For j = Len(Lookup_Valuel) To mincharmatch Step -1
                            If InStr(cell1, Left(Lookup_Valuel, j)) > 0 Or InStr(cell1, Right(Lookup_Valuel, j)) > 0 Then
                            
                                If Found <> "" Then
                                    If j > CInt(Mid(Found, WorksheetFunction.Search("|", Found) + 1, 99)) Then
                                    Found = cell.Value2 & "|" & j
                                    Set rng = cell
                                    End If
                                Else
                    
                                Found = cell.Value2 & "|" & j
                                Set rng = cell
                                End If
                            GoTo nextcell
                            End If
                        Next j


        End If
nextcell:
            
            Next cell
        
                    
        
            If Found <> "" Then
                If col > 0 Then
                Alookup = rng.Offset(0, col - 1).Value2
                ElseIf col < 0 Then
                Alookup = rng.Offset(0, col + 1).Value2
                Else
                Alookup = Left(Found, WorksheetFunction.Find("|", Found) - 1)
                End If
                ' Debug-Print Found
            Else
               
                Alookup = "No Match Found"
                
            End If
            
            
            
        End Function
```