# VBA SUM Variable Range

Tags: excel, vba, variables, sum, range

[image]

I want a code to sum the Variable rows up if certain condition is met.
e.g. If A12 is numeric and B12 is empty then insert a fomula in cell C12 to sum C3:C11.
Then perform the same action at C22 and C30.
The problem I have is don't know how to define the starting row.

```
Sub Test()
Dim y As Variant
Dim r As Variant
Dim StartRow As Variant

   LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For y = 3 To 500
            For r = 1 To LastRow

            If InStr(1, Cells(r, 1), "Amount") Then
                StartRow = r

            If IsNumeric(Cells(y, 1)) And IsEmpty(Cells(y, 2)) Then
            Cells(y, 3).Formula = "=SUM(C" & StartRow + 1 & ":C" & y - 1 & ")"
            End If
         End If
      Next r
  Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: You could do this with just an extra column and without needing VBA...

Comment: @LS_dev Since this is just a part of my whole code, so I want the VBA code to perform this, could you please help? ^ ^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub Test()
Dim y As Variant
Dim firstRow As Variant
Dim lastRow As Variant
lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
firstRow = Cells(lastRow, 3).End(xlUp).Row
If IsNumeric(Cells(lastRow + 1, 1)) And IsEmpty(Cells(lastRow + 1, 2)) Then
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Formula = "=SUM(C" & firstRow & ":C" & lastRow & ")"
End If
For y = firstRow To 3 Step -1
    lastRow = Cells(y, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    firstRow = Cells(lastRow, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    If firstRow < 3 Then firstRow = 3
    If IsNumeric(Cells(lastRow + 1, 1)) And IsEmpty(Cells(lastRow + 1, 2)) Then
        Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Formula = "=SUM(C" & firstRow & ":C" & lastRow & ")"
    End If
    y = firstRow
    If firstRow = 3 Then Exit Sub
  Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Abe, Excellent! It works! But May I know how to insert this condition? `If IsNumeric(Cells(y, 1)) And IsEmpty(Cells(y, 2)) Then`

Comment: Edited the answer to include that. Let me know if it doesn't work. I did not test it.

Comment: Hi Abe, this works perfectly! but...Still a question, the formula in C12 becomes SUM(C1:C11), what I want is C3:C11. Which part should I amend?

Comment: HaHa, I also changed `For y = firstRow To 3 Step -1` from 1 to 3 before, but it does not work, that's why I have to ask you.

Comment: There are a few other changes as well. Replace you code with this and see if it works.

Comment: Oh I see it ! `If firstRow < 3 Then firstRow = 3` Changed and this time really works perfectly! Thanks a lot for your patience to help me!